# Rails select tag selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My tag:

```
<%= select_tag(:option, options_for_select([['All', 1], ['Co', 2], ['Bought', 3], ['View', 4], ['Top API', 5], :selected => :option ])) %>
```

How do I set the selected value to which option is selected. For example, if I select `['Bought', 3]`, and submit, `['All', 1]` option is selected. How can I display the selected value after the form is submitted.

Comment: If you select `['Bought', 3]` in the browser and then submit, where are you seeing that `['All', 1]` was selected?  Can you show the rest of the form as well as the controller code relevant for the form action?

Comment: The options are closed ( `]` ) in the wrong place, so the browser see `:selected => :option` as one option. Fixing the problem, you can refresh the browser and the selected option will remain selected.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You did everything right, just close the options `]` before the `:selected => :option`:

instead of `...], selected: :option ]))`, change to `...]], selected: :option ))`

So, your code should be:

```
<%= select_tag(:option, options_for_select([['All', 1], ['Co', 2], ['Bought', 3], ['View', 4], ['Top API', 5]], selected: :option )) %>
```

Comment: How does that specify which value is selected?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
<%= select_tag(:option, options_for_select([['All', 1], ['Co', 2], ['Bought', 3], ['View', 4], ['Top API', 5]], :selected => params[:option])) %>
```

This works perfectly in rails 4.2

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to add a class to the tag:

```
<%= select_tag(:option, options_for_select([["Option 1",1],["Option 2",2],["Option 3",3]], params[:option] ), class:"select") %>
```

Worrking in rails 5.